# Cancel job in queue (database driver) with late option

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I have a system with booking for a house renting with contract (all terms and conditions).

I put in a queue with job, an email with all terms and conditions (date etc..) which is sending when the booking is created and another with delay, to notify the customer 2 days before the stay.

But if I change the booking info (for example the date), I need to cancel the job in queue.

How can I do this ? I use the Database driver.

There is the line in BookingController :

```
dispatch( new ReminderMailJob( $booking, $booking->customer ) )->delay( Carbon::parse( $booking->ends_at )->subDays( 3 ) );
```

There is a screen of my database "jobs" table

[image]

How can I select one of this line and delete it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rework remider to schedule.

Comment: Hey @Maksim , could you explain a little more? thanks

Comment: Make command (for example) for send reminders for all contracts whom pass conditions in current moment and schedule it https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: What I think @Maksim is trying to say is to not create a reminder job when booking is created. You should use a scheduled command which looks for approved bookings created (IE 2 days ago) and dispatch the job at that moment

Comment: Ok I see, it's true that it's a better way to do it.

I'm making a job that will run every 24 hours (for example) and send an email to all bookings that arrive in less than 48 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling)

Make an [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#generating-commands) like

```
class SendReminers extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'booking:send-reminders';

    protected $description = 'Send a reminders email to a users';

    public function handle()
    {
        Booking::where(*your query*)
          ->each(fn($booking) => ReminderMailJob::dispatch($booking, $booking->customer)->now());
    }
}
```

Than schedule task for, example, five minutes

```
$schedule->command('booking:send-reminders')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

And now reminders will be sent only for bookings which are relevant at task execution moment.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your precious help.

I hadn't thought about it at all, thanks!

Comment: Small question, if I launch it every 24 hours (for example), how can I make it so that it does not send the email to those who have already been sent? Would adding a boolean field that I set to true when it's sent be the right way to do it, or is there something better?

Comment: Hm, maybe put flag in cache with key booking:{ID}:reminder. Or, in my opinion, best option is make something like Checklist - dedicated model for each booking - where you can store all flags - reminders, room ready, guest accept terms, etc.